# How to use plot function to plot results of your own function?

Tags: r, function, plot

I'm writing a short R package which contains a function. The function returns a list of vectors. I would like to use the plot function in order to plot by default a plot done with some of those vectors, add lines and add a new parameter.

As an example, if I use the `survival` package I can get the following:

```
library(survival)

data <- survfit(Surv(time, status == 2) ~ 1, data = pbc)

plot(data) # Plots the result of survfit
plot(data, conf.int = "none") # New parameter
```

In order to try to make a reproducible example:

```
f <- function(x, y){
  b <- x^2
  c <- y^2
  d <- x+y
  return(list(one = b, two = c, three = d))
}

dat <- f(3, 2)
```

So using `plot(dat)` I would like to get the same as `plot(dat$one, dat$two)`. I would also like to add one more (new) parameter that could be set to `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

Is this possible?

Comment: there is no `dat$a`, even less `plot$b`, what would be the desired result plot and why a custom function like `myplot <- function(mydat) plot(dat[[1]], dat[[2]], ...)` cannot satisfy you ?

Comment: I meant dat$one and dat$two (already edited), I know how to make my own funcion but I was wondering if it would be possible (and easy), because I think it's a more intuitive behaviour.

Comment: Try `plot(data.frame(dat[1:2]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be looking for classes. You can use the S3 system for this.

For your `survival` example, `data` has the class `survfit` (see `class(data)`). Then using `plot(data)` will look for a function called `plot.survfit`. That is actually a non-exported function in the `survival` package, at `survival:::plot.survfit`.

You can easily do the same for your package. For example, have a function that creates an object of class `my_class`, and then define a plotting method for that class:

```
f <- function(x, y){
  b <- x^2
  c <- y^2
  d <- x+y
  r <- list(one = b, two = c, three = d)
  class(r) <- c('list', 'my_class')       # this is the important bit.
  r
}

plot.my_class <- function(x) {
  plot(x$one, x$two)
}
```

Now your code should work:

```
dat <- f(3, 2)
plot(dat)
```

You can put anything in `plot.my_class` you want, including additional arguments, as long as your first argument is `x` and is the `my_class` object.

`plot` now calls `plot.my_class`, since `dat` is of class `my_class`.

You can also add other methods, e.g. for `print`.

There are many different plotting functions that can be called with `plot` for different classes, see `methods(plot)`

Also see Hadley's [Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) chapter on S3.